# Libgdx's ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferTexture() gets only pixels from certain 3D models

Tags: opengl, 3d, libgdx, screenshot

I'm trying to make a pause screen with the last frame of a 3D scene rendered to a texture, over which I would render a black rectangle with half alpha and some text.
I thought that using ...

```
ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferTexture()
```

... was the easiest option, but models whose textures lack of this attribute ...

```
BlendingAttribute(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
```

... would not be rendered at all in the screenshot.

Example:

[image: Pre] [image: Post]

Why is this happening?

Comment: I think that the black rectangle is overdraws the `Texture`s, without additive blending, what would be what you want. I think you have to set this `BlendingAttribute` to the `Material`, but i am new to libgx so i am not sure. Anyway, instead of using the `getFrameBufferTexture()` you could simply hold a `int state` in your class, and if `state == STATE_PAUSED` you just don't update the positions, rotations... of the objects. So you can stil render, like the game is not paused, and overdraw it with your text and the black rectangle

Comment: I removed the code that rendered the rectangle, and it keeps happening the same. Anyway, I think that was a good approach, thanks!. I could do what you said in order to pause the game, but I want to make the most of libgdx's Screens.

Comment: With my approach there is no need for a `PauseScreen`, and i don't think thats worse. In my oppinion using a `Screen` is only necessary, if the view and the resources you use totally change. In your case i would not use another `Screen`. But thats your choice (:
Another idea, that came into my mind: Are you rendering the scene with some light/environment? Maybe the `FrameBufferTexture` does not take care about them?

Comment: Make sure to update to latest nightly, there's been a related issue which is fixed a while ago.

Comment: Ok, that's it, solved! Classic trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this has already been fixed in the latest nightlies. Just update your project with them.